# Excel 2010 Custom Formula / Conditional Formatting to highlight data that is greater than Twice the Value of Original Cell

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, conditional-formatting, rules

I am trying to figure out how to indicate cells that are greater than twice the value when compared to a specific cell. For example, a value of .1 compared to .18 would be OK but .1 compared to .2 would make the cell highlighted since .1 doubled = .2 and anything greater would be false. I know how to make rules with cell value ranges... but the tricky part is my values will be changing and won't always be comparable to .1 
Another example: 3.2 compared to 5.6 is OK but 3.2 compared to 6.5 is NOT OK. (In this case the max limit would be 6.4)
Another example: 50 compared to 75 is OK but 50 compared to 110 is NOT OK. (In this case the max limit would be 100) Get the gist?

Would appreciate any advice please.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> compared to a specific cell.

Insert `$` before the row and the column (as in `$A$1`) for the value to compare to.
Unless you do, the comparison will be using RELATIVE referencing.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Conditional format command with the highlight greater than option. Click in the Format Cells that are Greater than box then click your reference cell. Immediately after add *2 then click ok. You will see something like =$C$4*2. That should do what I think you are asking for.